# How to stop/cancel a runnable when pressing on android phone's back button?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, back-button, android-handler

In my project, I have an activity called "ExamMenuActivity" where I can choose between "Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication and Division" activities.

In Addition activity (called ExamAdditionActivity) I have a handler method to regenerate the question form after a given answer. Everything seems working fine, I can generate the question and give an answer and after giving an answer, a new question is generated in 2 seconds.

The issue I am having is, after I give a correct or a wrong answer to the question, within 2 seconds, if I quickly press on the back button of the phone and don't wait for the question to regenerate, I come back to the Exam Menu page as I wanted (back to ExamMenuActivity) but the screen changes back to ExamAdditionActivity and I see a new generated question again.

So I want to be able to come back to Exam Menu activity again when I press on the back button of the phone before the question regenerates and I don't want to face back the ExamAdditionActivity again with a new generated question (say I changed my mind after giving an answer to an addition question and I wanted to choose another activity from the menu and I didn't wait for at least 2 seconds).
I have tried overriding the activity with onBackPressed method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

but unfortunately that didn't work.

Here is how I regenerate the question. I basically restart the same activity in two seconds with a handler ( there was a runnable within my handler code but since it was showing anonymous, android studio offered me to change it to a lambda function) :

```
private void regenerateQuestion() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
            Intent restartExamAdditionActivity = new Intent(ExamAdditionActivity.this, ExamAdditionActivity.class);

            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            startActivity(restartExamAdditionActivity);
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        }, TIME_OUT);

    }
```

Even though I am not sure but I think I am having the problem in button listeners area since I give an answer to the question and call regenetate() method there under each button.

I hope there can be an answer to my issue. Thank you so much for stopping by to check on my post!

Comment: Your question contains a lot of unnecessary information and code. In the future, you should concentrate on providing a minimal relevant example of the specific problem. A lot of readers here do not want to spend hours wading through your code to find the relevant bits. Just a tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your `Handler` as a member variable of your class, like this:

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler();
```

Create your `Runnable` as a member variable of your class, like this:

```
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent restartExamAdditionActivity = new Intent(ExamAdditionActivity.this, ExamAdditionActivity.class);

        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        startActivity(restartExamAdditionActivity);
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }
};
```

Post the `Runnable` using the new variable:

```
myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, TIME_OUT);
```

When you want to cancel the regeneration, do this:

```
myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
```

Comment: Dear @David Wasser. I really appreciate your answer. That was exactly what I have tried also. I have tried these two member variables in my void regenerate method like:

`private void regenerateQuestion(Handler myHandler, Runnable myRunnable) {

        myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, TIME_OUT);

    }`

Comment: and then tried to use these variables in override onBackPressed method like:

`@Override
    public void onBackPressed(Handler myHandler, Runnable myRunnable) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
        this.finish();
    }`

but then I get an error notification "Method does not override method from its superclass"

I just couldn't find out what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the new code snippets. Trying to read code in a comment is painful and confusing.

Comment: Ah...I see the problem. You dont' need to pass the variables to either method. Since `regenerateQuestion()` is a method of your `Activity`, it has access to all member variables in the `Activity`. Also, `onBackPressed()` is a method called from the Android framework, and it takes no arguments. Just remove the arguments from the declaration of `regenerateQuestion()` and `onBackPressed()`.

Comment: Thank you @David Wasser. I have tried to be more precise with my question and edited it as you suggested. I also updated my code and removed the arguments from `regenerateQuestion()` and `onBackPressed` declarations. I am now able to stop the runnable. Thank you very much! I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: Glad the issue is solved. Welcome to Stackoverflow!